# How to extract concrete struct from interface

Tags: go, struct, interface, sqlx

I have multiple database tables with a concrete struct for each table. I'm using sqlx. My functions for database access work fine for each concrete struct.

Since many of my database operations (e.g., insert a row) are identical across the tables I'd like to DRY them up a bit by having a common set of functions that take an interface and perform the operations.

In a function that takes the interface and calls sqlx functions (e.g., sqlx.Get) I need to pull the concrete struct out of the interface to hand to sqlx. And I'm stumped there.

I've read the [Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection). I've read the [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package documentation . I've looked all over and can't seem to put the pieces together properly.

Specific code:

```
type Persistable interface {
    DbFieldNames() []string
    DbPrepCreate() error
    TableName() string
}
```

`type Session struct {}` implements those methods and is accepted as a Persistable.

This statement works fine (with the concrete struct explicitly created.

```
// src is the Persistable passed into this function
dest := Session{}
err = stmt.Get(&dest, src)
```

But using that explicitly created struct in the common function defeats the purpose. What I want to do is this:

`dest := SomeFunctionThatExtractsTheConcreteStruct( src )` # such that I can pass that dest into sqlx.

I've used the reflect package to examine the src variable (type, value, kind, ......). I can easily see that src contains a *Session. I can get the real value out. But creating a concrete class from src to pass into sqlx eludes me.

Answer (score 3):

You have the variable named `src` with type `Persistable` containing a `*Session`.  Your goal is to get an `interface{}` value containing a `*Session` to use as the first argument to the Get method.

Because `Persistable` is assignable to `interface{}` (as are all types), you can simply pass `src` to the first argument of the Get method.

```
err = stmt.Get(src, args...)
```